# How to acquire multiple mutex in c

Tags: c, multithreading

I have an assignment to do, where I have 5 threads.

3 threads are responsible to write in 3 different files

1 thread is responsible to count time

1 thread is responsible to get the content of the 3 files and write it in another file at some point.

Thread0:

```
void *task0() {
    //Trigger conditions to the threads below
}
```

Thread0: Is responsible to count time, and notify the other threads.

Thread1:

```
void *task1(){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m1);
    while (!cond1)
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond1, &m1);
    // do some stuff
    cond1 = 0;
    writeToFile("file1.txt");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m1);
}
```

Thread1: Thread1 is notified by Thread0 in a random time. When Thread1 is awake it writes some data to file1.txt.

Thread2:

```
void *task2(){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m2);
    while (!cond2)
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond2, &m2);
    // do some stuff
    cond2 = 0;
    writeToFile("file2.txt");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m2);
}
```

Thread2: Thread2 is notified by Thread0 once in a hour. When Thread2 is awake it writes some data to file2.txt.

Thread3:

```
void *task3(){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m3);
    while (!cond3)
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond3, &m3);
    // do some stuff
    cond3 = 0;
    writeToFile("file3.txt");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m3);
}
```

Thread3: Thread3 is notified by Thread0 once per second. When Thread3 is awake it writes some data to file3.txt.

Thread4:

```
void *task4() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m4) 
    while (!cond4)
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond4, &m4);

    if ((pthread_mutex_trylock(&m3) == 0) &&
        (pthread_mutex_trylock(&m2) == 0) &&
        (pthread_mutex_trylock(&m1) == 0)) {
        // do some work
        // Copy the content of file1.txt, file2.txt and file3.txt to file4.txt
        writeToFile("file4.txt");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m1);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m2);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m3);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m4);
}
```

Thread 4: Thread4 is notified by Thread0 at every 2,5hours. When Thread4 is awake, it gets the content of file1, file2 and file3 and put into file4.

So in order to write file4, I have to acquire 3 mutexes: m1, m2 and m3 because I have data in 3 different critical sections(file1.txt, file2.txt and file3.txt).

My question is: The way I'm accessing the 3 critical sections in Thread4, to get those data and put it into file4 is correct ? Or Is there a better way to do that ?

If there is a better way to do that, could someone please explain that to me and maybe provide some example code ?

Comment: Since you have 3 different resources, I think it's completely fine for thread 4 to check 3 different mutex. However file 4 is an independent resource which is not read by any other threads so m4 is redundant. Sidenote:  Since thread 4 is notified every 2.5 hours, trylock will fail if the mutex being checked is locked by other threads and copy will not execute. The next cycle will start only after 2.5 hours.